# Routers VS coordinators

Tags: ios, xcode, design-patterns, architecture, mobile-application

I am an ios developer and trying to figure out the difference between the router in viper architecture and coordinator .
I really cant find a clear answer is the coordinator just considered a pattern so the router is just some kind of coordinator after all or they have different purpose ? And if so what are the differences

Answer (score 8):

They are both similar but router manages routing from a single view controller, while coordinator takes care of entire flow.

So in a given Coordinator you might get child coordinators which makes you take care of the entire flow.